# Delete string containing some words

Tags: php, string, text-files

How to delete all strings in a txt file which contains some words?

I try to do it using this script:

```
$f = "somefile.txt";
$str=file_get_contents($f);
$oldMessage=$_POST['label'];
$deletedFormat=' ';
$str=str_replace("$oldMessage", "$deletedFormat",$str);
file_put_contents($f, $str);
```

But my script deletes only one word not the whole string. 
Ideas?

Comment: The answer is already here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2352153/search-for-phrase-word-in-text-files-with-php

Comment: What do you mean by `string`? A single word is a string, a whole line is a string, the whole file is a string.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you want to just delete the entire `$oldMessage` if there is a certain word or? It would help if we could see the contents of `$oldMessage` probably.

Comment: I want to delete the line contains variable - $oldMessage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my solution:

```
$f = "somefile.txt";
$file = fopen ($f, 'r');
$oldMessage=$_POST['label'];
$deletedFormat=' ';
while(!feof($file)){
    $line = fgets($file);
    if (strpos($line , $oldMessage)) $arr[] = $line;
}
$str=file_get_contents($f);
foreach($arr as $needle){
    $str=str_replace($needle, $deletedFormat,$str);
}
file_put_contents($f, $str);
```

Comment: But how to delete all line where I found $oldMessage variable?

Comment: @Darkwind I've updated my answer. It works properly on my test txt file.